# How to access the database from a Codeigniter CLI

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, command-line-interface, codeigniter-3

I have a Codeigniter application that works well through the browser but I am struggling to get anything working properly on the command line. The following snippet is what I have in my controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Followers extends CI_Controller {

  public function process()
  {
    echo ENVIRONMENT.PHP_EOL;

    $this->db->select('n.`id`, n.`name`');
    $this->db->from('`table` n');
    $this->db->where('n.`active` = 1');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $results = $query->result_array();

  }

}
```

I run as follows:

```
php index.php cli followers process
```

And get the following:

```
development

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity:    Notice
Message:     Undefined property: Followers::$db
Filename:    /Users/neilthompson/Dropbox/Development/MAMP/htdocs/app/application/controllers/cli/Followers.php
Line Number: 14

Backtrace:
    File: /Users/neilthompson/Dropbox/Development/MAMP/htdocs/app/application/controllers/cli/Followers.php
    Line: 14
    Function: _error_handler

    File: /Users/neilthompson/Dropbox/Development/MAMP/htdocs/app/index.php
    Line: 343
    Function: require_once



An uncaught Exception was encountered

Type:        Error
Message:     Call to a member function select() on null
Filename:    /Users/neilthompson/Dropbox/Development/MAMP/htdocs/app/application/controllers/cli/Followers.php
Line Number: 14

Backtrace:
    File: /Users/neilthompson/Dropbox/Development/MAMP/htdocs/app/index.php
    Line: 343
    Function: require_once
```

I understand what the error is saying but not how to fix it!

I have the following in the autoload file:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'smartie' => 'smarty', 'session');
```

What do I have to do to be able to access the database?

Comment: why are u using queries in controller? where is your model, this is not a good approach to use framework standard

Comment: you're running your method incorrectly by doing `php index.php cli followers process`. When running via CLI, you should do `php index.php controller method "args"`. The way you do it, codeigniter looks for a controller named `cli` which does not exist

Comment: @JavierLarroulet the controller is in a subfolder called "cli" which is why it is like that.

Comment: @devpro I moved to a model and did $this->load->model('Followers'); and now the error is "Undefined property: Followers::$load". So while you are right that using a model is the correct approach actually moving to model makes no difference to the underlying issue.

Answer (score 2):

The issue turned out to be that running on the command line it didn't like using the hostname "localhost" to connect to the database. Changing this to 127.0.0.1 fixed it.